# Magento attributes in separate phtml files

Tags: magento-1.7, theme

I have 4 attributes inside my Magento for two of my products. In order to make jQuery tabs on product page with attribute values, I need to separate those values in phtml files.

Is there a way to retrieve an attribute value for a specific product inside a newly created phtml file?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this would be to create blocks that use the Catalog Product View block code, which grabs the product out of the registry.  Here's an example:

```
[yourtheme]/layout/local.xml
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info"> <!-- the name of the main product view from catalog.xml -->
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.tab.mytab1" template="path/to/tab.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>

[yourtheme]/template/path/to/tab.phtml
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<!-- Access whatever product property you need here -->
<?php echo $_product->getDescription() ?>
```

You can then just include the tab on your product view (inside your local catalog/product/view.phtml) with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.tab.mytab1') ?>` or whatever you choose to alias it as.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve attribute text on product view page:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('brand');// brand attribute input type is drop-down
$_product->getData('manufacturer');//manufacturer attribute type is text or textarea
```

And attributes which you want to output on product listing or product view page should be following options accordingly (see attribute edit page):

```
"Used in Product Listing" -> "Yes"
"Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" -> "Yes"
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you mean?

```
$quote  = $this->getQuote();
$quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();

// iterate through all items in the order
foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
    $myAttribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getAttributeText('my_attribute');
    // check the attribute
    if ( ($myAttribute != 'sexy') ) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Sorry, it is not sexy.'));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is definitely wrong.

Comment: Why is this 'definitely wrong'?

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The question is about the product display in the catalog. It has nothing to do with the quote.

Comment: Oh right. Soz, I misunderstood then.

Comment: @Marius I declined your flag because even wrong answer has a right to live as long as it is not violating any rules.

Comment: @Tim. I figured that out when I saw the 'declined' message near the flag in my account. It won't happen again :)

Comment: @Marius no worries, your activity is highly appreciated.

Comment: Tim you sound like Tuvok :) Cheers, thank you both for contributing and helping people online.